# Split/Strip a set of lines on encountering newline or comma

Tags: python

I have a set of lines in a textpad.

Eg:

```
643 ABCF aksdjgk 1q25hgn
239056 dsgkn 32968, 39859 ewktgklh, 35927369
9689846 dklsghdkls 23-608 dsklgnk
ewth834056 sidtguoi,235907 sdkgji,25689-8, 29067490,wtyuoew
```

How can I read this using python and have the text split into different list values on newline as well as `,` (comma)?

For instance, the output for the example text should come out as

```
643 ABCF aksdjgk 1q25hgn
239056 dsgkn 32968,
39859 ewktgklh,
35927369
9689846 dklsghdkls 23-608 dsklgnk
ewth834056 sidtguoi,
235907 sdkgji,
25689-8,
29067490,
wtyuoew
```

Comment: Your expected output has all the spaces intact, but the title mentions stripping. Which one is it?

Comment: Sorry, the spaces at the end of the lines can be trimmed..

Answer (score 6):

Try using `re.sub`, and replace all commas with comma followed by a newline:

```
result = re.sub(',\s*', ',\n', input)
```

Note that we actually match `,\s*`, to remove any whitespace which might occur after a comma separator.

Comment: Op keeps all the whitespace after the comma, despite what the title implies. +1 regardless

Comment: Not that OP wants this (after clarification), but you can replace with  ` '\\0\n'` to keep the spaces. I haven't tested, but `\\0` might actually have to be `\\g<0>` to work properly.

Comment: My answer appears to cover your expected output.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that "textpad" means text file, you have a couple of options. For a small file like the one shown, the easiest solution would be to `read` in the entire file as a string, and replace the commas with a comma + newline, as [@TimBiegeleisen's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54001140/2988730) shows.

For larger files, this may not be a good option due to memory constraints. In that case, and for the sake of generality, I like to iterate over the lines of a file. Here is a fairly simple generator that behaves like a normal file iterator, but also splits on commas:

```
from itertools import zip_longest, repeat
import re

def spliterator(file):
    for line in file:
        segments = re.split(r',\s*', line)
        ends = repeat(',\n', len(segments) - 1)
        for item in zip_longest(segments, ends, fillvalue=''):
            yield ''.join(item)
```

It would be pretty simple to make this accept the split pattern as an argument, optionally keep the trailing spaces, and return the whole line with newline characters inserted.

Using the generator is simple, since it just wraps a normal file object or any other iterable of lines:

```
with open('textpad.txt') as file:
    print(''.join(spliterator(file)))
```

Here is an [IDEOne link](https://ideone.com/5VWSiP) with a demo.

To get the contents of the whole file as though read in by `readlines`, just wrap in `list`:

```
lines = list(spliterator(file))
```

To write back to an open output file, use `writelines` directly:

```
output.writelines(spliterator(file))
```

Comment: @Asimo. Please don't change your question after you've received valid answers. Instead, select an answer and ask another question if you have to.

Comment: Let me revert back..Sorry for the hassle..
I have anways found a workaround to get the output in my desired format using your answer..
simply adding 

with open(r'H:\Messenger\test_Nov2.txt') as file:
    lines = ''.join(spliterator(file))
    

lines2 = lines.splitlines()

Comment: @Asimo. The change you made is something you should be able to figure out in your own, or at least attempt, given the answers posted here.

Comment: @asimo. Why not just `list(spliterator(file))`? No need for the extra hoops. Or you could just use the generator directly. I'm guessing you don't actually need the list.